# Spring MVC very confused about controller mappings

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, annotations

Using annotation-based controller mappings.

```
@Controller
public class AlertsController {

  @RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void create(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  }
}
```

When access `alerts/create`, I get the message `Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?`.  This seems odd, and counter to what the documentation says.

So, I add in a `RequestMapping` to the class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/alerts")
public class AlertsController {

  @RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void create(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  }
}
```

This, then, works.  I shouldn't need either `@RequestMapping`, but I do.  Now, things get weird.  I really wanted to map this to `/profile/alerts', so I change it to this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile/alerts")
public class AlertsController {

  @RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void create(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  }
}
```

I get a 404 when going to `profile/alerts/create`, but *it's still mapped to `/alerts/create`* for some reason?!?!?!

I change it to:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("foobar")
public class AlertsController {

  @RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void create(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  }
}
```

This is very strange and incredibly inconvenient.  Anyone have a way to fix this, or even debug what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

In your first snippet you missed the leading `/`. It should be something like `@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)`

Now you should change your third snippet to this,

```
@Controller
public class AlertsController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/profile/alerts/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void create(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  }
}
```

Moreover, as you are making your method `void` which expect the DispatcherServlet to fall back on the default view name of "profile/alerts/create". And then it is combined with a suitable view resolver. For example,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

And there you got 404, may be.

Comment: I had the view resolver, and this did work.  The weird thing is that I thought the `@RequestMapping` annotations on methods were refinements of the class-level annotation; it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do url matching on both the class annotation and more finegrained on the methods. The class level annotation gets prepended to the method level annotation

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  /* matches on /admin/users */
  public string users() {  ...  }
}
```

It's very close to your original third snippet except you forgot a leading /.